# I need 2 paypal accounts to be credited while making a single payment

Tags: paypal

I'm developing a B2C site where many shop enroll with the site and sell their products. The Site owner needs to get a 5% of the sales done through their site from the sellers. That is when a customer buys product for $100, $5 must be credited to the site owner's paypal account and 95$ must be credited to Seller's paypal account. Does paypal has this option already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's called chained payments. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#id091QF0I30YK